# How to redirect any nested urls same component in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have following in router

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: demo1Component,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: "demo2",
    component: demo2Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id', component: demo2Component}
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: "demo3",
    component: demo3Component
    ,canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
];
```

I want to redirect any thing like

```
demo2/1/url/hi

demo2/100/temp/h2

demo2/2300/hello/demo
```

to same demo2Component. How can I achieve that rather than writing everything explicitly?

From,
zen

Comment: Maybe use a wildcard route?: https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-wildcard-routes

Comment: Wildcard sounds good to me. or you if your path is relevant you can use a path that looks like this  with multiple params.
Check this in your demo2 route

`{ path: ':param1/:param2/:param3', component: demo2Component}`


In your demo2 component you will be able to get all your params

Comment: I am not sure how deep it can go, i just wanted to use wide card as  @R.Richards suggested. but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks @R.Richards, i had used wild card little differently then i though, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the `matcher` function from the angular Router.
You can do something like this in your `routing.module`:

```
matcher: (segments) => {
  if (Array.isArray(segments)) {
    const posParams = segments.reduce((prev, current, index) => {
      prev['cat' + index] = current;
      return prev;
    }, {});
    return {
      consumed: segments,
      posParams
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

With the code above you will collect all segments from your url in a array. You can go ahead and handle these information in a resolver and do what you want with it.